# Semantically Analyse words in a text document using wordnet

Tags: java, wordnet

I want to analyze  the  meaning of all the nouns in a text document and want annotate them as object/location etc. (or something similar)
For example if the text document contains,

```
      Stella went to the kitchen to get a knife.
```

I need to identify kitchen as a location and knife as an object.

For the moment I use the wordnet Rita with a java code and identify all the nouns in the text document and get the synset of each word.But I don't know how to analyze each and every meaning of  the word and identify the most relevant meaning according to the context and identify it as a object or location etc.

Comment: Do you want to semantically disambiguate/discriminate ? If so, WordNet alone probably doesn't help you much. You can look whether you find other words from related words in the context of the word.

Comment: I wonder if this question might gain more traction at linguistics.stackexchange.com, viz. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/870/225

Comment: What you're looking for is Named Entity Recognition. There are several options; use a Web API for NER such a OpenCalais or have a look at LingPipe e.g., which is a library you can include into your software (however, have a look at the license agreement if you're planning to use it commercially).

Comment: Thank you. I'll check in  linguistics.stackexchange.com. And currently I'm using Gate Embedded to identify person names etc. But I want to move to another method to identify comman nouns as the above example.